# Accessibility categories for social media data

Tags: metadata, social-media, open-definition, categories

What is the best way to generically categorise data in social media back-end databases within a context of level of openness?

Both academic sources and own thoughts and ideas are appreciated as I have struggled to find any categorisation of the sort.

I didn't come far and my definitions are not crystal clear but here is what I thought:

> `Open data` - *information that is open to anyone who requests it*. For instance the data that you can access when visiting an url to a Facebook profile without being logged in.
>
> `Open data with general limitations` - *information that is open to a user only if the user meets certain general requirements.* For instance the data that you can access when visiting an url to a Facebook profile while being logged in. Also data in open Facebook groups.
>
> `Open data with qualified limitations` - *information that is open to a user only if the user meets specific requirements.* For instance the data you can access if you are logged into your Facebook account and the Facebook profile you are visiting is a Facebook friend. Also data in Facebook groups that can be joined after being approved.
>
> `Locked data` - *information that is open only while being logged in as a specific user.* For instance that user's chatlogs, data hidden from everyone through privacy settings. Also data in secret Facebook groups.
>
> `Internal data` - *information available only to the provider of the service.* For instance every chatlog of every user.

I realise different social media use different standards. I hope this can be a categorisation in general terms.

Comment: You might want to consider checking the Open Data SE Meta, as this topic has been broached before.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorJ.Smith - do you have a specific post in mind?

Comment: Perhaps this thread, but I'd search around in there. Defining openness is a bit of a hot topic on Meta. http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15/whats-your-interpretation-of-the-open-in-open-data

Comment: Thank you again. This thread maybe belongs in Open Data SE Meta then? Should I move it there?

Comment: Hard to say. I would wait and see what others think. Worst case scenario, a mod might migrate the thread to Meta for you.

Comment: I suggest to leave it here. Your question is about (classification of) (open) data, not about the workings of this site.